# Tesseract OCR accuracy decreases when I used iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, ocr, tesseract

I am working with tesseract in one of my clients iPad project. I got 95% result when I used simulator but in device tesseracts accuracy is surprisingly decreased! I got 30% accuracy on device.

Can anyone share your experience ? Why I am not getting 95% accurate result in my device ?

Comment: OCR via the camera or via downloaded images?

Comment: no, I used photo library. That means I used the same image in simulator and device.

Comment: The iOS simulator uses actual processor instructions (i.e. x86 on the mac osx device) whenever it can to speed up simulation. You may be running into a situation where the numerics functioning in simulation (due to the above) are each higher accuracy then what is run on the ARM core on the actual device.

Comment: trumpetlicks, thanks for your information. can you suggest me how can I improve ocr occuracy in Device ?

Comment: no accuracy improve bcz tesseract free version OCR sdk and if your scan image high quality background image then result must done then not perfect. if you create powerful application then use anyline sdk an paid sdk use...